# Data fails to load from api only during debugging

Tags: asp.net, debugging, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I'm currently in the process of writing an ASP.NET core application and I'm getting data from a web api and loading the information in a grid and some dropdown menus.

This all works fine, but I've noticed that sometimes when I'm debugging and I step through the functions that make requests to the api and receive the data back from it, the data just fails to load in my application. Everything seems fine while I'm debugging, and this doesn't happen when I start my application by selecting "Start Without Debugging."

I would like to specify that this only happens when I step through the code; if I run the debugger without any break points it behaves correctly. In addition this behaviour is not *always* observable when I step through the code, and it is more likely to happen when I take a long time.

I'd like to know if anyone knows what exactly is causing this or can point me to some reading material that would help me understand it. I'm assuming it has something to do with stalling the requests or making them time out but I obviously need to learn more about what is happening.

Comment: Sounds like a race condition whereby "slowing down" the main thread is allowing something else to complete first when normally it wouldn't. It would help if you posted some code and indicated where your breakpoints are, otherwise all we can do is speculate.

Comment: @ToddMenier Thanks for the comment, but unfortunately I'm not in a position where I can post my code, although, I know that would be helpful.